# Find shape within rows of characters-Java

Tags: java, arrays, list, count, shapes

I came across to problem on thinking how to get the shape from the rows of characters, for example given this input:

```
AAAAAAAA    
ABBBAABA
ABABABBB
ABBBAAAA
AAAABBAA
ABBABBAA
ABBABBAA
ABAABBAA
```

Task:
Calculate how many shapes are there formed by horizontally or vertically adjacent 'B' letters.
In this example there are 4 such shapes.
It might be easier to see if I remove the 'A's:

```
 BBB  B 
 B B BBB
 BBB    
    BB  
 BB BB  
 BB BB  
 B  BB
```

Additional task:
How many 'B' characters are in each shape?
In this example: 8, 4, 5, 8 (not in any particular order).

I am still new to Java, so I want to ask is there is any java function that can check the same occurrence that near to each other in order to count the shape appears? Hope you can give me some pointer on how to construct this algorithm.
(I have thought of taking each index of 'B' and check whether they are near to other 'B' but I get stuck)

Comment: The requirements are not clear. What is the expected output for this given input?

Comment: @janos I just edited, thank you for your time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am still new to Java, so I want to ask is there is any java function that can check the same occurrence that near to each other in order to count the shape appears?

No, there is no built-in functionality to make this very easy.
And that's the point of the exercise.

Here are some example approaches you could use to solve this problem:

- [Flood fill](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flood_fill):

  - Convert the input to a matrix. It could be a `boolean[][]` where you set `true` where the input is `B`.
  - Iterate over the values in the matrix, skipping `false` values.
  - When you find a `true` value, initiate the flood fill:

    - Increment the count of shapes (you found a new shape)
    - Recursively replace all adjacent `true` values with `false`, incrementing `shapeSize` count as you go
    - When all `true` neighbors (and neighbors of neighbors, and so on) are replaced with `false`, the shape is fully explored
    - Continue the iteration where you left off, until you find another `true` value
- Graph theory: find [connected components](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connected_component_(graph_theory))

  - Convert the input to an undirected graph:

    - The index of each character can be the vertex id
    - Create a connection for adjacent pairs of `B` in the input
  - Iterate over the vertices of the graph
  - If a vertex doesn't have yet a component id, use depth-first search to find all the vertices connected to it, assign to all vertices the next component id, incrementing the `componentSize` count as you go
  - When there are no more connected vertices, the shape is fully explored
  - Continue the iteration where you left off, until you find another vertex with no component id
- [Union find](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjoint-set_data_structure): this is similar to finding the connected components

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply. I solved my problem, and it is similar to Flood Fill method. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

```
int indexCount = 0;
ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();

for(int a = 0; a < count; a++) {
    indexCount = array[a].indexOf('B');
    list.add(indexCount);
}

System.out.println(list);
```

Answer (score 0):

Method `indexof(int ch)` returns first index of apearing character in a String. you should cut each string after getting index of first B.

Or you can use `indexOf(int ch, int fromIndex)` that returns the index within this string of the first occurrence of the specified character, starting the search at the specified index.

Comment: I change to indexOf(0, a), but it gives me this result [-1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1]. By the way, thank you for your reply!

Comment: you should write `indexCount = array[a].indexOf('B' , indexCount+1);
        list.add(indexCount);`